# ConstraintViolationException when attempting to insert row containing a null value in a column that the database sets the default

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a table with a column ('requestLastUpdated') that does not allow nulls, but has a default value (getDate()) defined by the database. This field wasn't initially defined in the Java entity since it wasn't needed by the code at that time. Inserts worked fine and the database correctly set the time the insert occurred to that field. Now I'm adding some reporting functionality to the app and wish to read this value from the database, so I added this field to the entity. However now when the code attempts to insert data, I get: Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement...

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'requestLastUpdated', table 'dbo.myTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Is there any annotation or anything I can add to my entity to tell Hibernate that it's okay to attempt to persist a null value in a field the database has defined as non-nullable?

My entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RequestChild", schema = "dbo")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class RequestChild implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "childRequestId", nullable = false)
    private Long childRequestId;

    @Column(name = "parentId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long parentId;

    @Column(name = "itemId")
    private String itemId;

    @Column(name = "createTime")
    private String createTime; //This is the column that's not null in the database and things worked before it was added to this entity.
```

Comment: Can you please add the code.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Column(nullable = false)` annotation adds a not null constraint to the table **definition**, but ***Hibernate or any other framework*** will not perform any **validation** on the entity attribute. Hibernate just executes the SQL INSERT or UPDATE statement, and the database will validate the constraint. 
So, you can use `@Column(nullable = false)` annotation inside the entity.
It can create the SQL insert or update query and pass it to DB without inside-code valiation:

```
@Entity
public class YourClass {

    ...

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date requestLastUpdated;

    ...
}
```